# Paging sliders without using jquery UI

Tags: pagination

I want to build a pagination system like at the bottom of this site http://www.dirty.ru/.

The issue is, I dont want to use any UI. Is it at all possible? And does anyone have any examples for me?

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to use any "UI"? You don't want to use javascript? What server technology are you using? JSP, ASP.Net, PHP, Ruby on Rails etc

Comment: I'm using JSP. My terminology is below par for jquery and javascript. I don't want to use any libraries to implement something similar.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the `HTML5 input type="range"`: http://webhole.net/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/
If you're using Google Chrome you'll see what it looks like...

But since not all browsers support this, you might look into having a `div` with a border set to 1px, add a icon or whatever in a separate element and have jquery do the work...

Right out of the top of my head, and a quick look at their code, I think that is the way they've done it...
The range of pagenumber, I believe, they have putted in a ever wide div and prevented linebreakes, set `overflow:hidden;`. Then used jquery or something to move the content...

Comment: That is perfect...but i need it to work in IE 7, 8, 9 and firefox. Can you explain the div with the border thingy?

Comment: I found this http://refreshless.com/nouislider/, but not 100% sure how to implement it. Playing around with it though.